# iOS inject code when code is on compile by Xcode or clang

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, code-injection

Can I inject some special code  when iOS project code is compiling,not on runtime. I want insert a function into project any functions!

Just like this:

```
//the original code
//the filename is user_code.cpp
int f1(){ return 1; }
int f2(){ return 2; }
int f3(){ return 3; }
int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)f1();
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)f2();
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)f3();
    return 0;
}
//the injected code
int function_counter[3];
int f1(){ function_counter[0]++; return 1; }
int f2(){ function_counter[1]++; return 2; }
int f3(){ function_counter[2]++; return 3; }
```

Comment: just like this //the original code
//the filename is user_code.cpp
int f1(){
    return 1;
}
int f2(){
    return 2;
}
int f3(){
    return 3;
}
int main(){
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)f1();
   for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)f2();
   for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)f3();
   return 0;
}
//the injected code
int function_counter[3];
int f1(){
    function_counter[0]++;
    return 1;
}
int f2(){
    function_counter[1]++;
    return 2;
}
int f3(){
    function_counter[2]++;
    return 3;
}

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19346660/335858